# detect MPI first process to execute

Tags: c++, mpi

Im Working on MPI library with c++ language.
i need to read parameters from users for only 1 time
something like this:

```
if (rank==0 )
       {
           printf ("enter a,b: %d\n");
           scanf("%d",&a);
             scanf("%d",&b);
        std::vector<int> ab;
            ab.resize(2);
            ab[0]=a;
            ab[1]=b;
            for (int i=1;i<numtasks;i++)
            MPI_Send(&ab.front(),2,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
             MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      }
       else if (rank!=0)
       {MPI_Status status1;
     MPI_Request request1;
    std::vector<int> ab;
    ab.resize(2);
    std::vector<int> temp=ab;
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    while (temp==MinMax)*/
      MPI_Irecv(&ab.front(),2,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&request1);
      a=ab[0];
     b=ab[1];}
```

i mean i want one proccess read parameters and send them to all others

or any way to define shared parameters and read them one time>

Comment: I may be interrested by the function [`MPI_Bcast()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php)

Comment: thank u  it solved the problem  MPI_Bcast()  and MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)